# Is there a way to get child class file path in parent class?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a parent class file A.js and child class file B.js

```
//A.js
class A {
  constructor(){
    console.log(__filename)
  }
}

//B.js
class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
new B()
//will output A.js
```

Is there a way to get B.js path in a.js?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to track bottom to top approach yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to accomplish this by changing the constructor of A to take an argument like so:

```
class A {
    constructor(arg){
        console.log(arg)
    }
}

//B.js
class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super(__filename);
    }
}

new B();
```